# ensure static members are set at most once (C++)

Tags: c++, static-initialization

```
class Foo {
   public:
     static int& num() {
          static int aNum = 0; // initial value
          return aNum;
     }

     static void writer_func() { /* ... do stuff and assign a value to num() */ }

     // a bunch of functions that "read" num()
     static void reader_func1() { /* uses num() in read-only mode */}
     static void reader_func2() { /* uses num() in read-only mode */}

}
```

How do I ensure that all the `reader_func*()` functions do not assign value to `num()` ?

**Addendum**: In comments/answers, a few have suggested that I simply declare the field as a simple `static int num;`. That will not work because it can potentially violate [ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

The reason I had to employ this slightly "odd" pattern is to not violate ODR

Also, the restriction here is that writer_func() will be called by other code, and I can't just preemptively call writer_func() to init the value

Comment: What do you mean by "assign value to `num()`"? How can you assign a value to a function???

Comment: Is `writer_func` supposed to write to `aNum`? How do you plan on ensuring that `writer_func` is only called once?

Comment: @goodvibration please look carefully at the return type. (this is actually a pretty common pattern)

Comment: @Brian The "design" is taht writer_func() should be called once, but then it'd be good to know if somehow num() is assigned to more than once, which would imply that somehow writer_func() might be called more than once

Comment: Well, I wouldn't quite phrase it as "assign a value to a function". More like, "assign a value to the reference returned from a function".

Comment: @goodvibration That pattern is typically used to ensure a static value exists when assigned by say, the c'tor of another variable.

Comment: In any case, I would just handle the assignment **inside** the function, instead of returning a reference. This way, you can ensure full control of that variable.

Comment: The C++ way would be to use a const subobject containing the int, provided it could be initialized at construction time.

Comment: Another reason for using this pattern is to ensure if you "include" the header in multiple places, you won't get different copies of `num()`. (if you were to define it as a simple `static int num`, you'd have a problem!)

Comment: anyway, I dont want the discussion to get side-tracked. Let's just say using this pattern is the "fixed" part of the equation. so I'd appreciate if you guys won't suggest changing that part

Comment: @goodvibration That would just make it awkward to get the value of the static.

Comment: Why is that even a class, if it has no state and all methods are static. Anyway, how about returning `const int&` from `num()`?

Comment: @Joker_vD `writer_func()` needs to be able to assign a value to it. (the goal here is to ensure it's done that at most once)

Comment: @OneTwoThree I know you think using this pattern is "the fixed part of the equation" but the fact is this is a textbook example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do? I'd wager good money there's a much simpler way.

Comment: P.S: You're right, though, in that it doens't have to be a class. It's just my OOO habbit

Answer (score 1):

It's not especially elegant, but since you mention that `writer_func` could potentially be called more than once, you could do something like:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static const int& num();

    static void writer_func();

    // a bunch of functions that "read" num()
    static void reader_func1() { /* uses num() in read-only mode */}
    static void reader_func2() { /* uses num() in read-only mode */}

};

class Num {
    static int& num() {
        static int aNum = 0; // initial value
        return aNum;
    }
    friend const int& Foo::num();
    friend void Foo::writer_func();
};

const int& Foo::num() {
    return Num::num();
}

void Foo::writer_func() {
    /* ... do stuff and assign a value to num() */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with it is to create a class that allows one time modification of the value and use an instance of the class.

```
class OneTimeWrite
{
   public:

      OneTimeWrite() : value_(0), isset_(false) {}

      int get() const { return value_; };

      void set(int v)
      {
         if ( isset_ )
         {
            throw std::runtim_error("Value must not be set more than once.");
         }

         isset_ = true;
         value_ = val;
      }

   private:

      int value_;
      bool isset_;
}

class Foo
{
   public:
     static OneTimeWrite aNum;

     // ...    
}
```

Comment: I'd have that toss an exception if `get()` is called before the value is set.  I'll also point out the code as currently posted isn't multithread-safe.  Not a problem in a guaranteed-to-be single-threaded environment, but if there's any chance it will ever wind up in a multithreaded application, that's something to worry about.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Multi-threading issues are foreign to me. I don't usually think about them.I trust you have valid concerns. Feel free to update the answer, if you are sure of what changes need to made.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you need to create a singleton class and allow modification only once:

```
class StaticContainer
{
public:
    static void setValue(int val){
        if (!isSet){
             isSet=true;
             value=val;
             std::cout<<"value changed to "<<val<<std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout<<"value cannot be changed\n";    
        }
    }
private:
    static bool isSet;
    static int value;
};

bool StaticContainer::isSet=false;
int StaticContainer::value;
int main()
{
    StaticContainer::setValue(10); 
    StaticContainer::setValue(20);     
}
```

Output:

> value changed to 10
>
> value cannot be changed

Comment: This will not work because it is potentially violating "ODR" (one definition rule).

Comment: It is also not thread-safe, if multiple threads called `setvalue()` at the same time.

Comment: for thread saefty you  can improve it later. Not adding it to make it readable and not confusing th reader.

Comment: For ODR, it depends on which application you  are running it. Simple exe, accross DLL. Could you give an example. In my example (simple main program) we don't have this issue and it is giving the expected behaviour or I am mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about a compile-time value, then what about making `aNum` a class-scope `static const`, *e.g.*:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static const int aNum;

    static const int& num() {
        return aNum;
    }

    static int writer_func() { /* ... do stuff and return a value, e.g.: */ return 1; }

    // a bunch of functions that "read" num()
    static void reader_func1() { /* uses num() in read-only mode */}
    static void reader_func2() { /* uses num() in read-only mode */}
};

const int Foo::aNum = Foo::writer_func();
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I can't just call `writer_func()`, it will be called as part of other call stacks

Answer (score 0):

Similar concept to [George's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48453437/3697870) suggestion, but with a neater/less sophisticated trade-off: wrap `num()` in a read-only version and prevent (by extra class funkiness or by a static coding rule) use of `num()` from `reader_func*()`.

```
class Foo {
   public:
     static int& num() {
          static int aNum = 0; // initial value
          return aNum;
     }

     static int num_ro() {
          int &aNum = num();
          return aNum;
     }

     static void writer_func() { /* ... do stuff and assign a value to num() */ }

     // a bunch of functions that "read" num()
     static void reader_func1() { /* uses num_ro() in read-only mode */}
     static void reader_func2() { /* uses num_ro() in read-only mode */}

};
```